# run a script and capture a Combobox with OnScreen Object mode with TestComplete

Tags: browser, combobox, testcomplete

Does anyone knows how to run a script and capture a Combobox with OnScreen Object mode with TestComplete in a web browser?

My JScript is like this:

```
function SelectComboboxItem(Combobox) {
    Log.Message(Combobox.ClassName);
}
```

Comment: It is unclear to me what you need to do. Could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: I want to run the above script for a web page.

Comment: As far as I understand, the main question is how to get the Combobox object that should be passed to the above script routine. Could you clarify what you mean by 'capture a Combobox with OnScreen Object mode'? Which browser do you use?

Comment: Yes, what i am trying to do is to get the Combobox object that should be passed to the above script, i also do not know how to get a Grid Object that should be passed to the script. I want to use the option "get onscreen Object" when i start the Script running the "run selected test script".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Object Spy](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/29324/) tool to capture the desired object. Get the full name of the object from the tool's window and use it in your script to call your script. For example:

```
function test()
{
  var obj = Sys.Process("MyProcess").WinFormsObject("MyForm").WinFormsObject("MyComboBox");
  SelectComboboxItem(obj);
}

function SelectComboboxItem(Combobox) {
    Log.Message(Combobox.ClassName);
}
```